# VBScript to determine registry string and kickoff batch file?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, registry, helper

I'm pretty new at scripting with VBScript.  What I've been attempting to do is write something to remove a program that we have three different versions of installed.  The only way I have found to easily differentiate between the three versions is a registry key with a string value that has the version number.

I figured I'd write a script that would check the registry to see which version was showing through that string.  However, each script I find is basically to figure out if the key exists, not the string, and doesn't allow me to call a function to kick off my batch scripts.  Below is one script I found that may/may not be a start to what I want to do.  Help?????

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Metalogix\PAM4Exchange Outlook Addin\ is the key, and the string is AddInVersion, REG_SZ, then a version number.

```
    Dim WshShell:Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.echo RegistryValueExists ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\")


Function RegistryValueExists (RegistryValue)
  'Ensure the last character is NOT a backslash (\) - if it is, we aren't looking for a value
  If (Right(RegistryValue, 1) = "\") Then
    'It's not a registry value we are looking for
    RegistryValueExists = false
  Else
    'If there isnt the value when we read it, it will return an error, so we need to resume
    On Error Resume Next

    'Try reading the value
    WshShell.RegRead RegistryValue

    'Catch the error
    Select Case Err
      Case 0:
        'Error Code 0 = 'success'
        RegistryValueExists = true
      Case Else
        'Any other error code is a failure code
        RegistryValueExists = false
    End Select

    'Turn error reporting back on
    On Error Goto 0
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The truth is you don't really need VBScript to achieve this. You can read that registry value directly from a batch file.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,3*" %%A in (`REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Metalogix\PAM4Exchange Outlook Addin" /v "AddInVersion"`) do if %%A==REG_SZ set AddInVersion=%%B
echo %AddInVersion%
```

You just need to add some code that will call your batch scripts, eg:

```
if "%AddInVersion%"=="1.0" call uninstall1.bat
if "%AddInVersion%"=="2.0" call uninstall2.bat
```